# Trying to return a record set using PHP & MySQL (inner join)

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP/MySQL to please bear with me. I am trying to have PHP write a table which returns a list of records from a join table. The SQL statement works perfectly when I run the query but I do not know how to write the function properly.

SQL statement which works:

---

```
SELECT members.nick_name, assets.asset_desc, shares.asset_cost, shares.percent_owner
          FROM 
            (shares INNER JOIN assets
            ON shares.asset_ID = assets.asset_ID)
            INNER JOIN members
            ON shares.member_ID = members.member_ID
            WHERE shares.member_ID = $member_ID"
```

---

My functions:

---

```
function get_shares_by_member($member_ID) {
global $db;
$query = "SELECT members.nick_name, assets.asset_desc, shares.asset_cost, shares.percent_owner
          FROM 
            (shares INNER JOIN assets
            ON shares.asset_ID = assets.asset_ID)
            INNER JOIN members
            ON shares.member_ID = members.member_ID
            WHERE shares.member_ID = $member_ID";
$share_result = $db->query($query);
$share_result = $share_result->fetch();
return $share_result;
}

function get_shares() {
global $db;
$query = "SELECT * FROM shares";
$share = $db->query($query);
$shares_table = $share->fetch();
return $share;
}
```

---

### My action:

```
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
$action = $_POST['action'];
} else if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
$action = $_GET['action'];
} else {
$action = 'list_shares';
}

if ($action == 'list_shares') {
if (!isset($member_ID)) {
    $member_ID = 0;
}
$shares = get_shares_by_member($member_ID);
$share = get_shares();
}
```

---

Here is my table:

---

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Nick Name</th>
    <th>Asset Description</th>
    <th>Asset Cost</th>
    <th class="right">% Ownership<th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($shares_table as $share) : ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $share['nick_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $share['asset_desc']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $share['asset_cost']; ?></td>
    <td class="right"><?php echo $share['percent_owner']; ?></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

---

I know this is a lot to ask but I've been struggling with this for the past 3 days. Any help will be much appreciated! If anyone needs help with AD/Exchange, I'd be happy to share my knowledge in that area!

Thanks!!

Comment: Which DB library are you using? What does the ->fetch() call do? Fetch a single row? the entire result set?

Comment: @Progger: what is the problem that you are facing? Does the code does not work? Any errors?

Comment: Please post `var_dump($share)` and `var_dump($shares)` after you call the two functions so we can see what they should contain.

Comment: @MarcB: The fetch() is supposed to return an entire result set, not a single row. As far as which DB library i'm using, I wish I could answer that! I will post the code which opens the mysql connection

Comment: @Abhay: I keep getting an error saying that i'm not using the proper parameters with my fetch() statement. I will post the exact message shortly (sorry, not in front of my dev machine.

Comment: @Michael: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you're asking me. I am really new to this. I am using a PHP/MySQL book to find examples of code to modify so that it will work for what I am trying to do!

Comment: Could part of the problem be that you are getting confused with the returns?  The get_shares_by_member returns $share, which is being mapped to $shares when called, and "get_shares" returns $shares back to $share.

Comment: @gabe3886: I'm definitely confused. Probably with more than just the returns. If you can give me some suggestions on how this should be written, that would be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can debug this step by step?

Comment: Hey @Progger: a few suggestions:

Comment: I realized that I had multiple problems with my code and this question is no longer sufficient. I will close this out and ask a more specific question. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see on here, this will produce a blank table with however many rows are returned for a number of reasons:

- None of the columns returned by the get_shares_by_member function are share_ID or asset_ID, so those columns won't be filled in.
- You are referencing percent_owner from $shares which, assuming is an array as you are using it in a 'foreach' loop, will need an index to reference it, or it should otherwise be $share['percent_owner']
- The percent_owner field will be put in the 'asset cost' column at present as there is no blank cell produced to move it to the '% ownership' column where it would seem logical to have it.

Based on what you have posted so far, the following should suit your needs:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Nick Name</th>
        <th>Asset Description</th>
        <th>Asset Cost</th>
        <th class="right">% Ownership<th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($shares as $share) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $share['nick_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $share['asset_desc']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $share['asset_cost']; ?></td>
        <td class="right"><?php echo $shares['percent_owner']; ?></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

I would recommend changing either the $share variable in the foreach, or the $share which is being set by get_shares().  Personally speaking, I would change the latter from

```
$share = get_shares();
```

to something like:

```
$shares_table = get_shares();
```

as it is essentially containing all of the information from the shares table, assuming the database abstraction layer function fetch() returns all results.

There could also be an issue when you are doing:

```
$share = $db->query($query);
$share = $share->fetch();
```

Going from different database abstraction layers I have seen, I would expect fetch() to be done as (using your variables)

```
$share = $db->fetch();
```

If the fetch() is requiring a result to be passed into it, then I would expect the code to look similar to:

```
$share_result = $db->query($query);
$share = $db->fetch($share_result);
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested, for the most part. I wasn't sure exactly which function you were referring to when asking about the fetch() as both of my functions use fetch(). I edited my original post with the modified code. I am not getting any errors now but I am not getting any results. Is there a tool I can use to check my code piece by piece?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

a few points:

1. are you sure your query does not return any errors? If there are
   errors, that might cause fetch() to fail
2. what DB class are you using? I would suggest that you please check
   that there is a fetch() function and what parameters does it accept? For example, the fetch() may be invoked like $share_result->fetch() or $db->fetch() or $db->fetch($share_result) etc.
3. I might be wrong but it seems that the fetch() might be always
   returning the first row from the resultset. Perhaps you might need
   to do fetch() in a loop for reading all results

You may as well try using the default PHP functions. Here is a code snippet that explains how you may rewrite your functions using PHP's default mysql() library:

```
mysql_connect('your host', 'your user', 'your password'); function get_shares_by_member($member_ID) {
    $output = Array();
    $query = "SELECT members.nick_name, assets.asset_desc, shares.asset_cost, shares.percent_owner
              FROM 
                (shares INNER JOIN assets ON shares.asset_ID = assets.asset_ID)
                INNER JOIN members ON shares.member_ID = members.member_ID
                WHERE shares.member_ID = $member_ID";
    $share_result = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($share_result)) {
        $output[] = $row;
    }
    return $output;
}

function get_shares() {
    $output = Array();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM shares";
    $share = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($share)) {
        $output[] = $row;
    }
    return $output; 
}
```

Hope the above helps. Please feel free to let me know if there is anything that is not clear.

Comment: Hi @Abhay. Thanks for your feedback. The error I am getting now is "Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 11". Line 11 is: "while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($share_result)) {
        $output[] = $row;"

Comment: Hmmm! That most likely means $share_result does not reference a MySQL result-set but FALSE (boolean) perhaps, which means that the query returned an error. Can you please try doing `echo $query;` and see what it looks?

Comment: Ok, I made some of the changes you suggested and I am getting much better results! As I understand, the syntax for 'foreach' is "foreach ($array as $variable). $array in my situation would be "$share['nick_name']" so shouldn't my foreach be stated like: "foreach ($share as $variable)? You had me put the $share in the variable part. I reversed it and now I get 8 copies of my record being echoed. I can put anything in the $variable and it makes no difference - foreach ($share as $foo) or foreach ($share as $anything) both return 8 copies of my row.

Comment: I'm sorry Progger but I couldn't make sense of your last comment. Where does foreach() come from? What is $share['nick_name']? What is $share - is it an array or a MySQL resultset?

Comment: look at my code above labeled "Here is my table". In there you will see a foreach command which is supposed to build an html table showing the results. That array is $share. Does that make sense? This is what i was referring to in my previous post.

Comment: Well, nope that still doesn't hit me. I'm actually finding it a little difficult to understand where and what is the issue that you are facing. Anyways, looking into your code labeled "Here is my table", the foreach statement seems to be using a wrong variable. The foreach is reading from the array $shares_table but from what I see that isn't a right variable. In your code labeled "My action", you are doing `$shares = get_shares_by_member($member_ID);`. So this means $shares is the array that you should use in foreach, like `foreach ($shares as $share)`